# .change function to show hidden form

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a hidden form section based on the selection in another form. Whenever a user selects an option in the form, it should show the other form. The following code works in such a way if one moves their mouse over the single unhidden form:

```
$('id_35').hover(function(){

$('id_33').show();
});
```

I am however trying to display "id_33" when an actual option is selected in form 35.  Here is form 35's HTML, inside a JSP page:

```
<li class="form-line" id="id_35">
<label class="form-label-left" id="label_35" for="input_35">
Available Start Dates<span class="form-required">*</span>
</label>
<div id="cid_35" class="form-input"><span class="form-sub-label-container">
<select class="form-  dropdown validate[required]" style="width:500px" id="input_35" name="q35_availableStart"> <option value="">Please Select</option>  

<%
int evar = 0;
String[] xvar = rslt2.split(";") 
while (evar < StartDates.length) {
xvar = StartDates[evar].split(";");
out.println("<option value=\""+xvar[0]+"\">"+xvar[0]+"</option>");
evar++;
}
out.println("</select>");

%>            
<label class="form-sub-label" for="input_35"> Choose from the Available Start Dates </label></span>`enter code here`
</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
(Made it with a checkbox first so edited post, will now accept both `checkbox` or `option`)

```
$(document).on("change", ".show", function (event) {
    if (this.checked == true || this.value == "show") // Checkbox or Option
        $("#f2").show();
    else 
        $("#f2").hide();
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uVGDw/2/)

Comment: sorry, for some reason it just isnt working.  Thus far, only this works: $('id_35').hover(function(){
  $('id_33').show();
});

Comment: Update:  this works:     $(document).on("change", function (event)     
        $('id_33').show();

});

Comment: I just read somewhere, Selections with Options, have event handlers only on the select object itself, as opposed to the options. In client JS , onChange is the event , where as a checkbox relies on checked.  However you did it, this as close as I need it to be able to do something with this.

Comment: You really should use the other code, otherwise you have no control over WHEN the second form shows, it will show on any checkbox like that.

Comment: Now, I am using this code, but will study your logic as well to make it even more strict checking:$('id_35').on("change", function (event) {
    
        $('id_6').show(); // Present Available Classes

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#id_35').hover(function(){
  $('#id_33').show();
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with and without leading pound # , and I changed it to the following, but still no luck:   $('input_35').change(function(){
       $('id_33').show();
       });

Comment: Hi, I am sorry. I just realised that this won't work. This is the code to detect a change in a select list. I missed the li in your code. 

Tell me if I understand this correctly. You have your first <li> which is shown and a second one which is hidden. When someone hovers over the first one you want to unhide the second one?

Comment: id_35 is a large form portion of a JSP page, and id_33 is another very similar to id_35. Both are actually form selections.  In the case of id_35, I am asking users to select a date, in the case of id_33 they will select a class ( which just as a side note , is a class that is available on the date they chose).  In any case, I am just trying to hide id_33, and upon the user's selection in id_35 I want to show id_33.  The user can select any value / option , only 1 option, but I dont care/require to know which one, if they select a choice, I want to show id_33.  I seem to only get hover to work

Comment: so far, this is what works only to show id_33:  $('id_35').change(function(){
  $('id_33').show();
});   Removing "#" , hover then works.  However it would be more ideal if this was a result of the user selecting a choice , not just by moving their mouse over the page where the form exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a change event for that `select`

```
$("#input_35").change(function() {

    //If you want to show the form when a specific value has been selected
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    if (selectedValue == "condition_here") {
        $("#id_33").show();
    }
});
```